# CakePHP radius search using lat lng

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I have a table named 'cities' where there are two fields named lat, lng. Now I want to search cities within 100 miles using the user provided lat, lng. My code id as follows..

```
            $lat = $latLng['lat']; // user provide lat 
            $lng = $latLng['lng']; // user provide lat
             $facilities = $this->City->find('all', array(
                'fields' => array('(((acos(sin((".$lat."*pi()/180)) * 
                    sin((`City.lat`*pi()/180))+cos((".$lat."*pi()/180)) * 
                    cos((`City.lat`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$lng."- `City.lng`)* 
                    pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515
                ) as distance', 'City.name', 'City.description' ), 
                'conditions' => array('City.distance' < 20)
            ));
```

it's giving error "Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'City.lat' in 'field list'"

Answer (score 1):

### SQL Injections

First of all, if you do not have casted/sanitized/escaped the user input, then what you have there is a nice SQL injection vulnerability, fields are not being escaped like for example conditions. **Remember, never ever directly insert user data into queries!**

### Quoting column names

The column is unknown because it in fact doesn't exist, you are passing `City.lng` as the column name, not just `lng` and a table name of `City`, in order to do so you'd have to properly quote these two separately, that is

```
`City`.`lng`
```

### Referencing aggregated columns in WHERE clauses is not possible

I don't know which DBMS you are using, but this is true for MySQL, Postgre as well as SQL Server. You cannot use the aggregated `distance` column in your `WHERE` conditions, you'd have to use `HAVING`, or reintroduce the very same calculation in the `WHERE` clause again (which is what [**virtual fields**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) would do).

A `HAVING` clause can be slipped in like this:

```
'conditions' => [
    // ...
    '1=1 HAVING distance < 20'
]
```

Also note that you have to use the exact alias, ie just `distance`, not `City.distance` like in your conditions (which also have an invalid syntax, `'City.distance' < 20` is an expression that will evaluate to `true`).